# Simple file read with Scala ARM library

Tags: scala

I am using the [ARM library](https://github.com/jsuereth/scala-arm) to read a resource file into a string. The code I'm using is this:

```
def readResource(reosurceName: String): String = {
  val res = for (writer <- managed(new StringWriter);
                 is     <- managed(this.getClass.getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(resourceName))) yield {
    IOUtils.copy(is, writer)
    writer.toString
  }
  res.acquireAndGet(identity)
}
```

It looks a bit weird to me, especially the last part with `acquireAndGet` of `identity`. Is there a better way ?

The general question would be, how would you use this style to do something like this

```
val x: String=
  for (res1 <- managed(...);
       res2 <- managed(...);
       ...
       resn <- managed) yield {
      f(res1, res2, ..., resn)
  }
```

The behavior is that if the operations within the for comprehension fail I would like the exception to be propagated out of the method and the resources should be closed.

I saw that map on a `ManagedResource` returns an `ExtractableManagedResource` from which I can extract the result using the `opt` method. `flatMap` returns only a `ManagedResource`. Is there a reason for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find it weird too that `map` and `flatMap` should behave in a slightly different way.
Maybe the mapping operation gives more freedom to expose a simplified result that can't be obtained through flatMap.

Anyway you could structure the code as follows to get something that looks more appealing

```
def readResource(resourceName: String): Option[String] = {
  val managedWriter = {
      managed(new StringWriter) and
      managed(this.getClass.getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(resourceName))
    } map { case (writer, is) => 
        IOUtils.copy(is, writer)
        writer.toString
    }
  }
  managedWriter.opt
}
```

*warn: the code is not tested*